# How chrome's dev tools differentiates between different request types?

Tags: apache, google-chrome, request, devtools

there is this `filters` tab in chrome's dev tools, which allows for switching between different request types:

[image: dev tools filters]

I'd like to know if there is some specification dev tools is following in order to differentiate between different request types.

I need this because in my apache server I'd like to recognise all `Doc` type requests.

Maybe I am approaching the problem incorrectly, if so please correct me.

Thanks

Comment: I can see there is this Fetch Metadata Request Headers standard (https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/).
Unfortunately it looks like it is not supported in some browsers.

Comment: I went with checking `Accept` header in apache if it contains `text/html`, for now it appears to be sufficient for my needs. Still, if somebody would share some insight as to how Chrome differentiates between request types, it would be still very helpful.